# Comparing property of an object in an array with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, splice

I am trying to compare the property of an object in an array with separate array and, if the property matches the separate array, remove the object from the first array. Is there a better way for me to do this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i].property === array2[j]) {
            array1.splice(i, 1)
            console.log(array1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = array1.filter(e1 => !array2.includes(e1.property))
```

Basically you will filter every element from `array1` such that element's property is not in the array2.

Is it what you want?